# Can a nuclear electromagnetic transition rate be affected by the electron configuration (e.g. bare nucleus v neutral atom)? Any experimental examples?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, radiation

When an atomic nucleus undergoes a transition and emits a gamma ray, the wave function of the nucleus changes, which can result in a *slight* redistribution in charge.

Some electron orbitals have a finite probability near $r=0$ and so will overlap with the nuclear charge distribution.

This leads me to suspect that the electromagnetic transition *rate* of a nucleus can sometimes be slightly sensitive to whether the nucleus is bare or in a neutral atom replete with $Z$ electrons.

But I could be wrong.

**Question:** Can a nuclear electromagnetic transition rate be affected by the electron configuration (e.g. bare nucleus vs neutral atom)? Are there any experimental examples of this?

Comment: There are atoms that are stable, but make radioactive ions. I can never remember what they are. I think they're at GSI.

Comment: @JEB the atoms are at GSI? Like in a bottle or something? :-) Yes those guys do all kins of interesting things with heavy ions, including seeing things [that aren't there](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.75.2658) ;-)